# How to complete MASQUERADE with NetPlan?

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, iptables

I'm an Ubuntu newbie, I'm going to use Ubuntu to set up a KVM virtual machine, I only have a public IP, I know how to configure it in ifupdown, but I want to configure it in NetPlan.

My configuration in /etc/network/interface looks like this.

```
auto vmbr0
 iface vmbr0 inet static
  address 107.175.49.24/32
  gateway 107.175.49.1
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
  bridge-ports ens3
  bridge-stp off
  bridge-fd 0
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

auto vmbr1
 iface vmbr1 inet static
  address 192.168.0.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  bridge_ports none
  bridge_stp off
  bridge_fd 0
  post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.0.0/24' -o br0 -j MASQUERADE
  post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '192.168.0.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
 iface vmbr1 inet6 static
  address 2001:470:89c7:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
  netmask 48
  bridge_ports tun0
  bridge-stp off
  bridge-fd 0
```

IPv4 is bound to ens3, IPv6 is bound to tun0, and NAT forwarding is enabled.

I am not able to specify parameters in netplan, when running netplan try it gives the **br0: reverting custom parameters for bridges and bonds is not supported** error, even if I force netplan apply it does not change anything.

Now my NetPlan configuration is as follows:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      addresses:
          - "107.175.49.24/32"
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - "8.8.8.8"
      interfaces:
        - ens3
      routes:
        - to: "0.0.0.0/0"
          via: "107.175.49.1"
          metric: 1
    br1:
      addresses:
        - "192.168.0.1/24"
        - "2001:470:89c7::1/64"
```

I now need to solve two problems, how to declare bridge-stp in NetPlan, because he does not accept bridges under the parameters included parameters, and how to use NetPlan to add NAT forwarding

***Other automation schemes are also accepted, but iptables-persistent is sometimes executed before br1 is up, so no rules can be added, and it will not uninstall the rules as br1 is shutdown.***